# JSON multiple category filter

Tags: jquery, json

I am wanting to filter a JSON product array based on a category criteria. Perhaps the solution will be to set up the JSON differently, but I am not sure what that JSON would look like. Here is my current JSON:

```
var myData = {
    "products": [
        {
            "name": "Multi Color 1",
            "price": "2.99",
            "color": [
                {
                    "type": "red"
                },
                {
                    "type": "blue"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Multi Color 2",
            "price": "2.99",
            "color": [
                {
                    "type": "red"
                },
                {
                    "type": "green"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Single Color",
            "price": "2.99",
            "color": [
                {
                    "type": "red"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So if I am filtering by 'red', it would return all three products. But if filtering by 'green' or 'blue' it would only return one product. I have tried $.grep and $.map, but I cannot get the multiple levels to return the products correctly. Any help is much appreciated.

One of my attempts was:

```
testMap = $.grep(myData.products, function(element, index) {
    return $.grep(element.color, function( element, index ) {
        return (element.value === "green");

    });
});
```

Comment: changing `color` to `"color": ["red","green"]` would simplify filter a bit but isn't a show stopper. Show the code you have been trying with first though. Showing your attempts makes it not look like you want others to do your work for you

Comment: Thanks charlietfl. I edited to add one attempt, I was just going through different code in jsfiddle. I am going to try with the simplified color array.

Comment: OK...so you were pretty close....better to learn from what went slightly wrong than start from scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sticking to using jQuery `$.grep` which is basically  wrapper for `Array.prototype.filter()`

```
function filterByColor(colorSearch, arr){
    return $.grep(arr,function(item){
        return $.grep(item.color,function(col){
            return col.type === colorSearch
        }).length;            
    });    
}

console.log(filterByColor('red',myData.products))
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yno3Lxe6/)**</kbd>

EDIT: Fix to your posted code. Needed to return length of inner array which acts as boolean, and change to `element.type`

```
testMap = $.grep(myData.products, function(element, index) {
    return $.grep(element.color, function( element, index ) {
        // check the `type`
        return (element.type === "green");
     // return the length , zero means no match and is falsy
    }).length;
});
```

FINALLY:

A change to `color:['red', 'green']` structure would simplfy to:

```
 testMap = $.grep(myData.products, function(element, index) {
      return $.inArray('green', element.color) > -1;
 });
```

Comment: Thank you! I continued playing around with it and had a $.grep embedded in $.map solution, but yours is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, what you want is:

```
filteredData = grep(myData, function(item) {
  return any(item.color, function(color) {
    return color.type === myColor;
  });
});
```

Where `any` is a function which tells you whether any of the items in an array satisfy a certain predicate. AFAIK jQuery has no such function out of the box, but it's easy to write one.

Translated into plain JavaScript, the whole thing involves a couple of nested loops:

```
var filterMyData = function(data, color) {
  var result = [];
  var products = data.products;
  for(var i = 0, n = products.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var product = products[i];
    var colors = product.color;
    for(var j = 0, m = colors.length; j < m; ++j) {
      if(colors[j].type === color) {
        result.push(products);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
};

console.log(filterMyData(myData, 'red'));
```